# Chef rbenv cookbook recipe user not found

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, chef

I have a problem with Chef rbenv cookbook. Once I start to bootstrap a server it gives me a error:

```
could not find user recipe for cookbook rbenv
```

But the recipe is in the recipes folder.
I can not get it to work even if I define the recipe in the role as well.

```
recipe rbenv
recipe rbenv::user
```

This is how I try to install user ruby in role:

```
  :rbenv => {
    :user_rubies => ['1.9.3-p392'],
    :global  => '1.9.3-p392',
    :user_installs => [
      {
        :user    => 'rubyuser',
        :global  => '1.9.3-p392',
        :rubies  => ['1.9.3-p392'],
        :gems    => {
          '1.9.3-p392' => [
            { :name => 'bundler' },
            { :name => 'capistrano' },
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

I have tried to add user.rb recipe and user_install.rb recipe to rbenv cookbook in server /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rbenv/recipes/ folder by hand, but that does not help me either.
Theres nothing that needs rbenv before it runs the rbenv install. It gives me the error when it starts to install it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is still an open question to you, but just for reference:  There are at least *two* `rbenv` cookbooks, [fnichol's](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv) and [RiotGames'](https://github.com/RiotGames/rbenv-cookbook) (which is linked [from the community site](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/rbenv)).

Only Fletcher Nichol's `rbenv` cookbook has a `user` recipe.